# How to create angular <popover-content> dynamically?

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to create some angular  dynamically. 
Statically created  works. 
eg.

```
<div>
    <popover-content #pop1
                     title="Hello"
                     placement="right"
                     [closeOnClickOutside]="true">
            Popup One
    </popover-content>

    <popover-content #pop2
                     title="Hello"
                     placement="right"
                     [closeOnClickOutside]="true">
            Popup Two
    </popover-content>

    Testing this <span [popover]="pop1" [popoverOnHover]="true">Pop1</span>.
    Testing this <span [popover]="pop2" [popoverOnHover]="true">Pop2</span>.
</div>
```

Now, I want to create these s dynamically from my data. 
But then it doesn't work with this #pop1/#pop2 thing.

Non-working code:

```
<div>
        <popover-content *ngFor="let p of allPops; let index = index"
                         #pop{{index}}
                         title="Hello"
                         placement="right"
                         [closeOnClickOutside]="true">
                {{p.message}}
        </popover-content>

        Testing this <span [popover]="pop1" [popoverOnHover]="true">Pop1</span>.
        Testing this <span [popover]="pop2" [popoverOnHover]="true">Pop2</span>.
    </div>
```

So, this `#pop{{index}}` doesn't work. I also tried with the following style `[attr.id]="'#pop' + index"`. Doesn't work too. So what's so special about this # inside a custom tag? How can I dynamically create it and make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible, more about this issue here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4581

> Sorry, anchors have to be statically analyzable and hence can not be dynamically generated. Same way as you can not dynamically create local variables in programing languages.

Local references are not suitable for such a thing I am afraid...

Btw local template reference is not the same as `id` attribute. The thing you tried would work just for assigning the `id` attribute, prefixed with `#`.

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars